# How can I extracting information about a structure from a LLVM IR?

Tags: llvm, llvm-ir

This is my C code. I want to get the information about struct demo1 and struct demo2 from a LLVM IR.

```
#include<stdio.h>

struct demo1 {
    long long A;
    long long B;

};
struct demo2 {
    long long C;
    long long D;
};

int main(){
    struct demo1 d1;
    struct demo2 d2;
    d1.A = 0;
    d2.C = 0;
    return 0;
}
```

LLVM IR ：

```
%struct.demo1 = type { i64, i64 }
%struct.demo2 = type { i64, i64 }

; Function Attrs: noinline nounwind optnone uwtable
define dso_local i32 @main() #0 {
  %1 = alloca i32, align 4
  %2 = alloca %struct.demo1, align 8
  %3 = alloca %struct.demo2, align 8
  store i32 0, i32* %1, align 4
  %4 = getelementptr inbounds %struct.demo1, %struct.demo1* %2, i32 0, i32 0
  store i64 0, i64* %4, align 8
  %5 = getelementptr inbounds %struct.demo2, %struct.demo2* %3, i32 0, i32 0
  store i64 0, i64* %5, align 8
  ret i32 0
}
```

How do I do this, I am currently able to access the following "`; Function Attrs: noinline nounwind optnone uwtable`"，but I want to get the first two lines of information "`%struct.demo1 = type { i64, i64 } %struct.demo2 = type { i64, i64 }`" and name of the member variable of the structure.

Comment: You could get those structs [from the alloca](https://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1AllocaInst.html#a074617b3e2f9f98ee3a2ac208e8e7210). LLVM IR struct fields don't have names, they're accessed by index. You could try using the debug information to get a name. but of course the debug information may not be present. The noinline etc. are [function attributes](https://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1Function.html#a7477aafbbe989ad35b96fac186d8e9fd).

Comment: Can I use the -O0 -g parameter to generate debug information in LLVM IR and then manipulate this debug information?

Comment: Well, you can, you don't even need -O0, but debug info can be a bit of a time drain. Consider carefully whether you really need those names.

Comment: ok, thank you very much, actually my real purpose is written in another question I just posted, can you take a look and provide some help?